# How compareTo method works here to sort objects one by one

Tags: java, collections

I am unable to understand how two objects are compared in the statement this.User.compareTo(arg0.User) .I want to know  flow of comparing object like what "this" refers when "arg0" is being compared.

```
public class Other implements Comparable<Other>{  // making objects of this class
    public String User;
    public String Pass;
    public String getUser() {
        return User;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {  //getter and setter
        User = user;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return Pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        Pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Other arg0) {                   // overriding to comapre objects
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return this.User.compareTo(arg0.User); //here how objects are compared like what "this " 
                              //refers here when we are passing list in Collections.sort(list); 
    }


}
```

---

This is the main class

```
import java.util.*; 

public class demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Other a=new Other();       //creating objects
        a.User="farma";
        a.Pass="123";
        Other a1=new Other();
        a1.User="arma";
        a1.Pass="123";


        Other a2=new Other();
        a2.User="brma";
        a2.Pass="123";
        List<Other> list=new ArrayList<Other>();

        list.add(a);
        list.add(a1);
        list.add(a2);

        Collections.sort(list);                   //sorting

        for (Other other : list) {                         
            System.out.println(other.User+" "+other.Pass);         //printing values
            System.out.println("");

        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: fixed the horrible code format for you.  Can you help to make sure you learnt the basics of Java naming convention? field name start with upper-case and class name starts with lower case is going to confuse people

Comment: To answer your question briefly: you cannot see the `compareTo()` method being use directly, because it is the internal logic of `Collections.sort()` that uses it.  You do not and should not care of how it is called, as long as you have a guarantee that: "if you can provide the logic to compare two `Other` in `compareTo()`, `Colleciton.sort()` will be able to sort the collection for you"

Comment: I will take care of naming conventions....thanks for telling me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 return this.User.compareTo(arg0.User);
```

When you write that line, you are comparing the User object's and returning the result.

Coming `this`, that points to current instance, when you pass Other to this method it invoke on the current instance which compares to the passed objects `User`.

If you see the signature of

```
public class Other implements Comparable<Other>{  // making objects of this class
    public String User;
```

There is a String object called `User` in other class.

So the sorting happens depends on the name of the users.

**Edit :**

When you use sort method on Collections, after all the delegations happend, it uses the  [Sorting algorithms](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.mergeSort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29). Look at the algorithm to check with.

Comment: Collections.sort(list); here am i passing User 's object i.e is in List?? so which object will pass first  a,a1,a2?? AND how current instance played role at this moment .

Comment: @Dani There must be always to objects to check with. One is current and the other is to check with. In process of sort each instance will check with others and move left right as per their order. You can check the sort source code attached to see how the algo works

Answer (score 1):

The `User` object in your `Other` class is actually a `String` variable (despite that you used uppercase, which is misleading).  As such, `Other.compareTo()` is using the `compareTo()` method from the Java `String` class.  It compares the `User` string (hence the `this` operator) belonging to the instance of an `Other` against another `Other` object.

The `String.compareTo()` method compares two strings lexigraphically, and returns the following (see [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm)):

> The value 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string; a value less than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically greater than this string; and a value greater than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically less than this string.

**Example:**

```
Other o1 = new Other();
o1.setUser("Tim Biegeleisen");
Other o2 = new Other();
o2.setUser("Suresh Atta");
System.out.println(o1.compareTo(o2));
```

This will output the value `1`, because the string `"Tim Biegeleisen"` is lexicographically *greater* than the string `"Suresh Atta"`.

Comment: SO this will work like as follows: -------------
ON FIRST ITERATION------------------------
this.User{farma}.compareTo(arg0.User{farma})-----------------------
this.User{farma}.compareTo(arg0.User{barma})-----------------------
this.User{farma}.compareTo(arg0.User{arma})